# Make a Startup message

Tags: scripts, startup

I just wanted to ask, if there is any way to create an error message that shows up after login and if I could combine it with a script to check the Internet connectivity.

Comment: So to understand that right youre login into a server or desktop?

Answer (score 7):

I created a script addressing your requirements:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# To check internet access after booting

ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
status=$?

if [ $status -eq 1 -o $status -eq 2 ]
then
    zenity --warning --text='<span foreground="red" font="15">Unable to establish Internet connection</span>' --title="Connection status"
fi
```

Save this as **`con_status.sh`** file in your home directory.

Provide execution permission by : `chmod a+x ~/con_status.sh`

Now open **Startup Applications** --> <kbd>Add</kbd>

Give it any name, any comment.

Command field : `sleep 8 && ~/con_status.sh`. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>.

That's all!

If there is no Internet connection at startup, it will show 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, you can use Startup Applications (Press Super/Windows key and type Startup Applications)

1. Create a shell script with your necessary code to check the internet
2. To display message to the user, I would suggest you use `notify-send`since its non-intrusive and simple. Take a look at this [notify-send](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/12/ubuntu-notify-send/) tutorial
3. Make your script executable `chmod a+x <script-name>.sh`
4. Reboot to check if its working or not